# Azure Fluent API - AppServicePlanOperations.ListMetricsWithHttpMessagesAsync Returns InternalServerError

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-app-service-plans, azure-sdk

The documentation for this method can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.iappserviceplansoperations.listmetricswithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Here is my code:

```
        var appServiceManager = AppServiceManager.Authenticate(credentials, subscriptionId);
        var filter = "(name.value eq 'CpuPercentage') and startTime eq '2017-10-06T08:00:00Z' and endTime eq '2017-10-06T09:00:00Z' and timeGrain eq duration'PT1H'";
        var metrics = appServiceManager.AppServicePlans.Inner.ListMetricsWithHttpMessagesAsync("myResourceGroupName", "myAppServicePlanName", false, filter).Result;
```

This is the only detailed exception I get:

> One or more errors occurred. (Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError') ---> Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'

The documentation says that `filter` is optional, which it's not (I get a BadRequest if I pass in `null`). I'm now providing one and now it throws an internal server error.

I've opened an issue on the `azure-sdk-for-net` repo but I'm hoping someone else can see if I'm making any mistakes in my `filter` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also can reproduce this issue on my side when using the code you mentioned. I find another [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent/1.3.0-beta) could be used for list the metrics of the resource, it is a **beta** version. I do a demo on my side, it works correctly on my side.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.ServiceBus.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.OData;

namespace MonitorDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var azureTenantId = "tenant Id";
            var azureSecretKey = "secret key";
            var azureAppId = "azure AD application Id";
            var subscriptionId = "subscription Id";
            var resourceGroup = "resource group name";
            var servicePlanName = "service plan name";
            var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(azureTenantId, azureAppId, azureSecretKey).Result;
            MonitorClient monitorClient = new MonitorClient(serviceCreds) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
            var resourceUri = $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/{servicePlanName}"; // resource id
            var metricNames = "name.value eq 'CpuPercentage'"; // could be concatenated with " or name.value eq '<another name>'" ... inside parentheses for more than one name.

            // The $filter can include time grain, which is optional when metricNames is present. The is forms a conjunction with the list of metric names described above.
            string timeGrain = " and timeGrain eq duration'PT5M'";

            // The $filter can also include a time range for the query; also a conjunction with the list of metrics and/or the time grain. Defaulting to 3 hours before the time of execution for these datetimes
            string startDate = " and startTime eq 2017-10-06T08:00:00Z";
            string endDate = " and endTime eq 2017-10-06T09:00:00Z";

            var odataFilterMetrics = new ODataQuery<MetricInner>(
                $"{metricNames}{timeGrain}{startDate}{endDate}");

            var metrics = monitorClient.Metrics.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceUri, odataFilterMetrics).Result;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent" version="1.3.0-beta" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.3" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.9" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.10" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net47" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for taking the time to reply. I'm going to play around with your findings and if it satisfies my needs, I'll accept your answer

Comment: May be I am missing something silly, but I am not able to resolve Namespace for MonitorClient

Comment: @RahulPatel I have the same issue, did you manage to resolve it?